# XQuery/XPath LIMIT a sum

Tags: xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0, xquery-3.0

I am new to XQuery. I need to limit by 1 in XQuery but I'm having trouble.

I am trying to find out the winner of a tournament by finding each players scores and summing up the scores to get the total scores. I then sort in descending order and try to limit the total score, however I am having problems with trying to limit in XQuery.

Here I am wanting to get the top score but I have tried to use subsequence($sequence, $starting-item, $number-of-items) and [position()] but it seems to not be working.

```
for $pair_ids in distinct-values(fn:doc("tourny.xml")/Competition[@date = "2012-12-12"]/Tennis/Partner/@pair_id)
let $total_scores := sum(fn:doc("tourny.xml")/Competition[@date = "2012-12-12"]/Tennis/Partner[@pair_id = $pair_ids]/@score)
order by $total_scores descending
return 
    $total_scores
```

the output is giving me:

```
$total_scores:
34
11
20
```

How can I limit the result so I only get 34 as the highest score?
Thanks

Comment: how about return fn:max($total_scores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fn:max()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-max) function as follow:

```
fn:max(
for $pair_ids in distinct-values(fn:doc("tourny.xml")/Competition[@date = "2012-12-12"]/Tennis/Partner/@pair_id)
let $total_scores := sum(fn:doc("tourny.xml")/Competition[@date = "2012-12-12"]/Tennis/Partner[@pair_id = $pair_ids]/@score)
order by $total_scores descending
return $total_scores
)
```

Comment: If you use `fn:max()`, you don't need the order by. Alternately, you could keep the order by, wrap the entire FLWOR clause in parenthesis, and use a positional predicate: `( ... )[1]`